# Sull'uso del vocabolo "meteoropatico"

Tags: word-usage

Una collega che ha vissuto per alcuni anni in Italia mi ha spiegato che aveva sentito alcune volte qualificare una persona come "meteoropatica". Questo fatto mi è sembrato veramente curioso. Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meteoropatico/), "meteoropatico" ha queste due accezioni:

> **1.** agg. Relativo a meteoropatia: *disturbi m.*; *forma, sindrome meteoropatica*.
>
> **2.** agg. e s. m. Che soffre di meteoropatia: *soggetto m.*; *un m., una meteoropatica*.

Ho cercato anche il [significato di "meteoropatia"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/meteoropatia/) e ho trovato:

> Nel linguaggio medico, disturbo o complesso di disturbi determinati dalle condizioni e variazioni meteorologiche (temperatura, pressione, umidità, azione dei venti, stati pretemporaleschi, ecc.), frequenti spec. nei soggetti con particolare labilità del sistema neurovegetativo.

La mia domanda è sull'uso che se ne fa nella lingua italiana. Secondo la [Wikipedia catalana](https://ca.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoropatia), il vocabolo "meteoropatia" esiste anche nella mia lingua, ma io non l'avevo mai sentito prima, quindi immagino si tratti di un vocabolo tecnico che si usi soltanto nel linguaggio medico. È lo stesso in italiano o si usa anche nel linguaggio comune?

Un'altra domanda: quando una persona viene chiamata "meteoropatica" è perché è andata dal medico e questo le ha fatto la diagnosi dei disturbi descritti dal Treccani? O a volte si dà al vocabolo un senso diciamo "più ampio"? Potreste farmi alcun esempio di situazioni in cui si usa il vocabolo "meteoropatico"?

Comment: Anche se meno “corretta” etimologicamente, si sente in giro, nel senso colloquiale chiarito nelle risposte, anche la forma “meteopatico”. Sarebbe invece fermamente da evitare la forma *“metereopatico” (come tutte quelle in cui si scrive erroneamente *“metereo-” al posto di “meteoro-”).

Comment: Personalmente ho più familiarità col termine usato in senso colloquiale che scientifico. La mia impressione è che, al di  fuori  di un contesto clinico, il termine venga  principalmente usato col dignificato "più ampio". Qui puoi trovare esempi di come viene usato: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=meteoropatico%2Cmetereopatico&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmeteoropatico%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmetereopatico%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61: Vedo che ci sono parecchi libri con il termine "metereopatico" invece di "meteoropatico".

Comment: @Charo - sì sebbene qualcuno affermi che è errata senza dire il perché.

Comment: @Josh61: Il libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* di Vittorio Coletti (Il Mulino, Bologna, 2015) parla di questo errore nel vocabolo "meteorologico" (derivato da *meteora*), frequentemente scritto erroneamente **metereologico* per un fenomeno chiamato "metatesi" (inversione di due fonemi).

Comment: @Josh61: E, nel link che avevi messo prima, c'è scritto *"metoreopatia"! Veramente un "pasticcio"!

Comment: @Josh61: In questo sito sarebbe offensivo ricordare perché scrivere *“metereo-” al posto di “meteoro-” sia una varietà non standard di italiano, un po' come *“magliale” e *“rivoluzzione”.

Comment: @DaG - molti user stranieri penso sarebbero contenti di sapere perché, anche perché come notato da Charo il termine è diffuso, e qualcuno mi insegna che se un termine viene comunemente usato....

Comment: @Charo: Ci sono persino libri in cui è scritto “non c'è ne sono”, se è per questo...

Comment: @Josh61: Ha già risposto Charo.

Comment: Ho aggiunto un punto al mio intervento sulle [Common misconceptions](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/common-misconceptions-when-discussing-language) nel Meta, per chiarire perché se alcuni parlanti si discostano dallo standard non creano automaticamente una nuova norma, nonostante sia così che alla lunga nascono nuove norme.

Comment: C'è da dire che molte persone si definiscono "meteoropatiche" (o, in maniera errata ma molto più diffusa, soprattutto nel parlato, "mete*reo*patiche") facendo confusione tra meteoropatia e meteorismo (che è tutt'altra patologia) e che molte delle persone che si dichiarano meteoropatiche nel senso corretto del termine, lo fanno in seguito ad una auto-diagnosi, perché soffrono di vari disturbi che loro stesse associano ai cambiamenti atmosferici.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il termine "meteoropatico" è utilizzato anche nel linguaggio comune, in assenza di precise diagnosi mediche.

Ad esempio, in seguito a un brusco cambiamento delle condizioni meteorologiche (in genere da soleggiato a piovoso, o simili), si può dire:

> Lo sai che non sopporto la pioggia, sono meteoropatico!

Tutto ciò senza che si manifestino quei disturbi psichici che dovrebbero essere presenti per considerare un soggetto meteoropatico. In effetti, nell'accezione comune "meteoropatico" è chiunque non sopporti ad esempio la pioggia, pur rimanendo in un ambiente chiuso, mentre il termine medico, come ricordato da @Josh61, implica una serie di disturbi psicofisici anche seri.

Comment: Nella mia esperienza difficilmente l'ho trovato usato in maniera riflessiva e di frequente in maniera negativa, per definire una persona dal carattere imprevedibile.

Comment: Per quanto mi riguarda, ho sentito diverse persone autodefinirsi meteoropatici senza alcuna accezione negativa.